# How to prove that the XOR problem for dimension d is not lineary seperable

Tags: systems-of-equations, neural-networks, theorem-provers

The 2 dimensions xor problem can be converted to 4 equations which is possible to prove that are not possible to solve

```
  x1       x2     output
  0         0         0
  0         1         1
  1         0         1
  1         1         0

w1*0 + w2*0 <= 0
w1*0 + w2*1 > 0
w1*1 + w2*0 > 0
w1*1 + w2*1 <= 0
```

How can I prove that the XOR problem for dimension d is not lineary seperable?
How to relate to an even d and an odd d?

I thought of the following answer:
Lets observe all of the equations of the form:

```
0*w1 + .. + 1*wi + .. + 0*wd > 0, for each i=1..d
```

These equations obligate wi > 0, for each i.

Now lets take the last equation.

```
1*w1 + 1*w2 + ... + 1*wd <= 0 (only when d is even)
```

This equation force wi<=0 for all i.

So:

```
wi > 0, for each i.
wi<=0 for all i.
```

Cannot be solved because.
On the odd - d case, we'll have to consider the all of the equations with 1 zero (d equations), and it will get to the same contradiction.

But - i'm not sure it's the good-practice way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for 2 dimensions can be true even for $d>2$.

Consider the vectors:
$(1, 0, 0, ..., 0)$
$(0, 1, 0, ..., 0)$
$(1, 1, 0, ..., 0)$

You can't have $w1, w2$ s.t.
$w_1>0, w_2 >0$
$w_1 + w_2 \leq 0$

edit:
this is for the equations that you posted for when $b=0$,
for $b \neq 0$, see Arthur's answer

Answer (score 0):

If $XOR_d(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$ is the (linear) XOR function on $d$ variables (defined as 1 iff an odd number of the inputs are 1), then define the two functions
$$
f(x_1)=XOR_d(x_1,0,0,\ldots,0)=w_1x_1+a\\
g(x_1)=XOR_d(x_1,0,0,\ldots,0,1)=w_1x_1+b
$$
But $f$ is (strictly) increasing and $g$ is (strictly) decreasing, which is impossible.

Comment: I didn't understad your proof, what do you mean by first item of x1? 
where are the equations? 
Thanks